workqueue in gcloud run
For Work Queue in Kubernetes
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/
wonder how to achieve that with cloud run? I asked Gemini and was directed to link but that's much more complex than a redis-backed workqueue as in the Kubernetes example. Anything more straightforward?

Are you searching for this document? Please elaborate on your requirement.

Thanks, but service is too complicated..
